# Tips on self-learning boot-time fundamentals (grub, disks, partitions, LVMs, etc)?

Tags: partitioning, grub

Is there any good resource which I can use to self-learn all the low-level system administration details on Grub, Grub2, disks, partitioning, LVM, etc? I'm comfortable with system admin tasks **post-boot** but I lack knowledge about both the fundamentals and actuals of all that happens **during boot** on a Linux system such as Fedora.

Any recommendations on how to setup a testbed on my desktop for learning the above? I may not be able to get another machine / harddisk, so may have to rely on something like VirtualBox. But don't know if there are other (better) options... so asking for tips from those who have self-learned / mastered this track themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the spare time, and (virtual) Machine you could try http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/.
Since you'll have to setup all the boot options yourself you will get a fair understanding of how these things work